# Confusion over solving basic problem involving vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

As said in the title, I am having trouble solving this problem:

*Find the component form of the vector that represents the velocity of an airplane descending at a speed of 100 mph at an angle of 30 degrees below the horizontal.*

This is what I worked out:

- The magnitude of the vector is 100
- That the direction angle would be 30 degrees
- Then, I would put the values into the trigonmetric form of a vector formula to get

$$v=(50\sqrt{3},50)$$

But, when I look at the answer, the book has the answer as

$$v=(-50\sqrt{3},-50)$$

All it has for work is this:

[image]

The part that I don't understand is how the book came to the conclusion that the direction angle is 210 degrees. Can someone please explain this to me?

Comment: Key phrase is "Below the Horizontal" meaning it's going down. As to the $x$ component I'm not sure. I think there's some picture missing that defines the coordinate system.

Comment: Depending on which side of the plane you're on the answer could either be $(50\sqrt{3},-50)$ (i.e. $-30^\circ$) or $(-50\sqrt{3},-50)$ (i.e. $-150^\circ$).  The question doesn't give enough info to distinguish between these two.

Comment: Huh, all that is in the book is what I put in the question. No other pictures. @Bye_World

Comment: OK.  Well your teacher will just have to accept either answer.  But the reason it's either $-30^\circ$ (which is coterminal with $330^\circ$ if you prefer) or $-150^\circ$ ($210^\circ$) is that the plane is *descending* and thus the angle should be **below** the $x$-axis.

Comment: Alright. Thanks @Bye_World